# RESTAngular - DELETE, not working as it should

Tags: angularjs, restangular, http-delete

If i am not mistaken in RESTful services in order to remove a record you need to do this:

`Delete a product: DELETE  /api/product/id` ([reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations))

But in RESTAngular when i do for example

```
product.remove();
```

A `DELETE` request is made to `/api/product` whith the whole product object in the Requests Body. This is not what i want!

Here is my code:

```
myApp.factory('RESTService', [ 'Restangular', function (Restangular) {
    var restAngular = Restangular.withConfig(function (Configurer) {
        Configurer.setBaseUrl('/myAPI/');
    });
    var service = {};
    service.Product= restAngular.service('product');
    return service;
}]);
```

GET one Product

```
RESTService.Product.one(id).get().then(function (response) {
    $scope.product= response;
})
```

DELETE the Product

```
$scope.product.remove();
```

I want when i do `product.remove()` to send a DELETE Request to /myAPI/product/id. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// DELETE /accounts/123/buildings/456
Restangular.one("accounts", 123).one("buildings", 456).remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a record using `RESTFul($http)` Service like this

```
$http.delete('/myAPI/product' + id, {params: {id: id}});
```

Comment: why two answers, you can update it with the previous one

Comment: @Nidhishkrishnan - I am new to stackoverflow i have some difficulties to create links when i post answer can u please help me?

Comment: which links, you mean an external URL links like jsfiddle, jsbin etc

Comment: @Archana take a look at this http://i.stack.imgur.com/HoPUs.png, also create an account in jsfiddle for getting and for posting jsfiddle url, for jsbin and plunker there is no need of any user account